# Getting Canvas is not available error on IE11 using flot charts

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, flot

I have a strange problem.
I have a flot chart code. When I run the code locally (developed using .net), it runs great on FF and chrome. It also runs well on my own computers IE11.

When running the code from the server - it runs ok on FF and chrome like before, but on IE11 it throws an error:
"Canvas is not available. If you're using IE with a fall-back such as Excanvas, then there's either a mistake in your conditional include, or the page has no DOCTYPE and is rendering in Quirks Mode."

I have included excanvas.js, tried changing the DOCTYPE to STRICT but still - nothing fixes this.

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed - it seems I used a version of Excanvas which is different from the one used on flot charts. I still don't get why this worked locally on my machine, but what the heck :)

Comment: For `IE11` you don't need excanvas (only for IE 8 and lower).  Are you conditionalizing it's include?  `<!--[if lte IE 8]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->`